# KeyListener does not react to keyboard event. Ok for mouse events

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jpanel, keyevent

JPanel reacts very strange to events. It could process the MouseEvent, but won't handle KeyEvent.

JPanel class:

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    class DrawListener extends MouseAdapter implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // works fine
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {       
            // works fine
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // works fine
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // Listener is NOT invoked here if anykey is pressed
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // NOT invoked 
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // NOT invoked 
        }
```

Constructor for panel:

```
// Class constructor
public DrawPanel() {
        DrawListener l = new DrawListener();
        addMouseListener(l);
        addMouseMotionListener(l);
        addKeyListener(l);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
}
```

How is it possible, if MouseEvent handler works just fine? Where it could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KeyListener` will only respond to key events if the component it is registered to is focusable AND has keyboard focus.

This is a known issue with `KeyListener`.

The best choice is to make use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which allows you to control the focus level that the key events will occur at.

Comment: As usual, @MadProgrammer's answer comes up within 5 minutes and provides exact and precise information. Is there any way to automatically upvote anything he posts? :)